# Wordpress template_directory in javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I try to use aSync load of css files in WordPress.
This still works with the full link to the file.

function loadCSS( href, before, media ){

```
"use strict"; var ss = window.document.createElement( "link" );

    var ref = before || window.document.getElementsByTagName( "script" )[ 0 ];

    ss.rel = "stylesheet"; ss.href = href; ss.media = "only x";

    ref.parentNode.insertBefore( ss, ref );

    setTimeout( function(){ ss.media = media || "all"; } );

    return ss; 
}
loadCSS("https://example.com/wp/wp-content/themes/theme_name/inc/css/ptth_nav.min.css");
```

If you could assist me in getting the link into a variable. For example like:

loadCSS('template_directory + "/inc/css/ptth_nav.min.css"');

I already tried a lot, but has no success and my willing has left me

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89791/theme-path-in-javascript-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use "get\_template\_directory\_uri" in javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52962278/how-to-use-get-template-directory-uri-in-javascript-function)

Comment: Additional to CBroe suggestion (he guided you in a correct direction) and I'm adding one more point if you're using WordPress version greater than or equal to 4.5.0 use `wp_add_inline_script` instead of `wp_localize_script` because the first function is for adding JS variable and logics the second one for JS translation purpose but very long days, developer is using this for passing PHP values to the JS. Here is the link for `wp_add_inline_script`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/

Comment: Really thanks for your assistance. I tried it now in each way - without success.
I put the hole function in the function.php and tried it "internal" - without success.
I tried to let it in the extern located file and put extend the function with the described way - without success.